# How to run ASP.NET Core Kestrel server without logging and config files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, kestrel-http-server

I need to inject an ASP.NET Core web API server in the existing monolithic application. The main problem for me is to turn off all config files, environment config, logging and so on stuff.

I need only a pure code-controlled HTTP-server with MVC routing.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Initially it was released as a separate repo, https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer So you can use the old code. If you want to use the latest, then go to ASP.NET Core repo and merely pick up the files you need.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout my [gist](https://gist.github.com/pimbrouwers/4b8131a0fc312af01cb3e205423f43b2) for getting a very minimal kestrel instance/asp.net web app going.

To enable MVC, you change it as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebApp 
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args) {
      try {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
          .UseKestrel()
          .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000/;https://localhost:5001")
          .ConfigureServices(_configureServices)
          .Configure(_configure)
          .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();

        return 0;
      }
      catch {
        return -1;
      }
    }

    static Action<IServiceCollection> _configureServices = (services) => {
         services.AddControllersWithViews();
    };

    static Action<IApplicationBuilder> _configure = app => {
      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
          endpoints.MapControllers();
      });

      app.Run((ctx) => ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Page not found."));
    };
  }
}
```

This also takes advantage of the new async capabilities of the entry point `Main(string[] args)`, wraps the server startup in a try/catch, and registers a catch-all not found handler.